# Subversion 1.7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, svnserve

I'm trying to install subversion 1.7.5 as a service on a Win Server 2008 R2 VM. Here's what I'm feeding to sc create:

`sc create subversion binpath= "c:\Subversion\svnserve.exe --service –r c:\SubversionData --log-file c:\SubversionData\svnserve.log" displayname= "Subversion Service" depend= Tcpip start= auto`

There are no typos, and the directories exist and are accessible. The service installs fine, but when I start the service, I get "The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." This error appears right away.

If I start svnserve as a daemon, with the same params:

`svnserve -d –r c:\SubversionData --log-file c:\SubversionData\svnserve.log`

Then it starts fine and runs fine.

Further, if I create the service without the `-r` param, the service then starts fine. (But can't find my repos.)

My thought is that this is permissions-related, since I've used the exact same method on other versions of Windows. But note that the daemon has no problems with permissions, while the service fails whether it's run as Local System or as me (I'm an Administrator).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be user error, with an assist from Microsoft.

I had stored the sc create command line in a Word doc with steps for setting up svn, and apparently Word autocorrected `-r` to `–r` (that's an en-dash instead of a hyphen). In Notepad and on the command line, the characters were indistinguishable, but when I opened RegEdit to look at the service entries, it jumped right out at me.

Move along, nothing to see here!